# Order Masonry Items for Most Efficient Layout

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I am using [jquery-isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to create a masonry layout of blog posts on a website I am working on. The layout is two columns, and there are two post types - long form writing, and image-only posts.

Masonry is working wonderfully, but I'm running into some issues with how I want the elements ordered.  The image-only posts are significantly shorter in height than the long form writing.  Isotope moves through the list of elements and chooses the most ideal position for each item, **based on the positions of previously placed elements**.

The problem is that if I have two short image-only posts output before a long form post, the layout can get really long in one column and really short in the other.  I'm seeing layouts that look like this:

[image: bad masonry layout]

I don't much care about ordering the blog posts by any piece of data (date, author, category, etc.).  I really just care that the layout looks nice.  It would be great if Isotope positioned elements based on the most efficient/condensed layout.  The less whitespace, the better.  In a perfect world, the layout would have looked like:

[image: good masonry layout]

Does anyone know of a way to get Isotope - or any other masonry library - to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything out-of-the-box that would help with this, but you can add the functionality yourself..

You can [extend Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/extending-isotope.html) to provide your own [custom layout mode](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/extending-isotope.html#custom_layout_modes). The extension points are pretty straight-forward and you can re-use much of the [masonry logic](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/blob/master/jquery.isotope.js#L921).

The issue is that the default masonry logic uses a greedy algorithm. You can do better by first sorting items by height, and assigning the next-tallest element to whichever row is currently shorter. This is an optimization of the [Partitioning Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_greedy_algorithm). Once you have items assigned to rows, you can re-sort within the row by date.

Where the masonry logic is `O(n)`, this would be `O(n*log(n))`. But since your number of elements is small, I wouldn't worry about the complexity.

Comment: No code: implementation left as an exercise for the reader :)